# Is there a way to queue up the next song on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, music.app

Is there a way to pick which song should play after the current song finishes?

I often browse my music library while listening, and I'll want to play a specific song, but not stop the current song in the middle. Is there a way to queue up a song to start after the current one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As they say in the iPhone world, ["There's an app for that" (Review)](http://www.macstories.net/reviews/oncue-brings-great-queue-features-to-ipod-app/) :-) It's called [OnCue](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oncue-the-music-player/id389764676?mt=8).

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Play It Next](http://www.ucentrixsoftware.com/#), it does just that.

[image: Play It Next]

Answer (score 2):

You should get the [Music Queue Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-queue-player/id735084779?ls=1&mt=8), this app will solve your problem. It uses the iOS music library and iOS 7 design and allows you to manage queues of songs that you can update whilst playing. You can also save queues. It's the best app of this kind I've seen!

Answer (score 0):

This requires just a little preparation: first you need to be playing a playlist.

- create a new playlist
- add your first song
- hit 'Done'
- Play the song you've added
- hit the back button to view the playlist
- hit 'Edit'

At this point you can add and rearrange songs without interrupting playback.  I always miss the function 'Play in iTunes DJ' which iTunes on the Mac has, which would shortcut this whole process.

Answer (score 0):

[OnTheFly Playlist](https://itunes.apple.com/ua/app/onthefly-playlist/id541323730?alreadyRedirected=1&ign-mpt=uo=2&mt=8) does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Queue Music](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/queue-music/id594366068?mt=8) does exactly what you are asking for: